# php preg_match_all get second select box options

Tags: php, web-scraping, preg-match, file-get-contents, preg-match-all

I am applying preg_match_all on a webpage select box that i get from file_get_contents but the problem is that it is only getting first select box and is not able to get second select box and it's options. My code is

```
 $html = file_get_contents("https://www.amazon.co.jp/-/en/dp/B09C1PM7K3?th=1");
 $quantityMatch  = preg_match_all( '@(<option value="([^"]+)">([^<]+)</option>)@', $html, $quantity);

    $result = array();
    $k = 0;
    foreach ($quantity[0] as $i => $value){
        $result[$quantity[2][$i]] = $quantity[3][$i];
        $k = $i;
    }
    $finalQty = $quantity[3][$k];
    // print_r($result);
    dd($finalQty);
```

it is getting categories from this page but i need second select box that is the quantity of stock on the webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the data of the selected option with this link.
unselected if you search with a phrase like "<li"

```
<li ... data-dp-url="/dp/B09C1P6T71/ref=twister_B09GWCBGQ5?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1"
```

you can get data-dp-url for unselected option and you add your link
etc: https://www.amazon.co.jp/-/en/
and again file get content new url
that's your new option stock :)

Example: your new second option link:

```
https://www.amazon.co.jp/-/en/dp/B09C1Q11Z9/ref=twister_B09GWCBGQ5?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1
```

If you don't understand, I can write sample code and post it.

[image]
Red: unselected option
Black: selected option

For example second option product stock count:

```
$html = file_get_contents("https://www.amazon.co.jp/-/en/dp/B09C1PM7K3?th=1");
    $qq = preg_match_all( '@(data-dp-url="([^<]+)" )@', $html, $option);
    $link = "https://www.amazon.co.jp/-/en".str_replace("&amp;", '&', explode('"', $option[0][1])[1]);
    $html_new_option = file_get_contents($link);
    $quantityMatch  = preg_match_all( '@(<option value="([^"]+)">([^<]+)</option>)@', $html_new_option, $quantity);

    $result = array();
    $k = 0;
    foreach ($quantity[0] as $i => $value){
        $result[$quantity[2][$i]] = $quantity[3][$i];
        $k = $i;
    }
    $finalQty = $quantity[3][$k];
    dd($finalQty);
```

=> $option[0][WANT_OPTION_ORDER]

Comment: Sir this is not what i have asked for, I asked to get quantity on the page link. please check it well.

Comment: Don't want to check the availability of other options? Did I misunderstand?

Comment: no sir this is not actaully what i want

Comment: this is my whatsapp, +92 3172634024

Comment: Can you try the finally edited code I wrote?